# Value comparison of matrix elements in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, continuous

Say I have a 256 by 256 matrix. I would like to replace any values that are 'greater' or 'equal' to 10 with 1 and make the rest 0 i.e. (values < 10).

For example,

```
2   3 6 15 24 32 1  7  39 10 ....

1   5 7 11 19 10 20 28 9 ........

10 24 6 29 10 25 32 10 ..........

.................................

.................................
```

and I want the output to be:

```
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 ............

0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 ..............

1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ................

................................

................................
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
a = [3  2  6  6 ; 
     7  5  3  7 ; 
     7 10  8  9 ; 
     2  4  3 10];

b = ( a > 5 )
b = 
     0     0     1     1
     1     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: you will not get this result since there are no number greater than 10 in a. Also you don't need parenthesis.

Comment: Ha, I didn't know you can put semicolons after each row in a, but it works.

Comment: @yuk: It looks like Amro meant to type `b = ( a > 5 )`, but he put `10` instead.

Comment: yes of course, my bad.. also I like to put parentheses in such assignments as it makes the code more readable (to me at least)